# APIM replacement

Tags: ford

Need to replace the APIM on my 2019 explorer sport. I know i can easily remove and replace the bad one, but what do I need to program the new one? If I have to have the dealer do it does anybody know how many hours the manual says it would pay for this job?

Answer (score 0):

If the replacement APIM is not for your Explorer in particular, there's a good chance you'll have to reprogram it.  You could reprogram it yourself using [an OBDLink MX Bluetooth scanner](https://www.ebay.com/p/626198486?thm=1500), along with [FORScan for Windows with Extended License](https://forscan.org/download.html), for $100 total.  Watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7kXeslUqWQ) for detailed instructions.

Comment: This is a link only answer. While the links may theoretically provide the answers, what happens if they go stale? At that point, the answer becomes useless. Try bringing the information here and placing the links as reference.